# Pycharm using python 2.7 even though python 3.6 is selected

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda

I have installed python 3.6 and in my pycharm project interpreter is set to python 3.6, but when I run:

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
```

I get:

```
2.7.15 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Feb 11 2019, 17:15:24) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
```

I want to use python 3.6. How can I fix this?

Comment: Make sure in the Run Configuration for the script Python 3.6 is also used. Theoretically, there can be a different interpreter set, e.g. Python 2.7.